# Composition of 2 functions with same domain and range

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let f $\in$ R $\to$ R and g $\in$ R $\to$ R. 
If f $\circ$ g = id$\Re$, does that mean that g $\circ$ f will be equal to id$\Re$ as well?

Comment: No, $f\circ g=Id$ only tells you that $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective.

Comment: @Marcos: Not only that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x)=x\sin x$ and $g(x)=\min\{y\in [0,\infty)\,:\, y\sin y=x\}$. Then $f\circ g=id_{\Bbb R}$, but $g\circ f\ne id_\Bbb R$ because otherwise $f$ would be injective. In point of fact, the existence of a function $g$ such that $f\circ g=id$ is equivalent to surjectivity of $f$, and existence of a function $h$ such that $h\circ f=id$ is equivalent to injectivity of $f$, therefore any surjective and non-injective $f$ allows a counterexample. If both such functions exist for a given $f$, though, then they must coincide.

Comment: Thank you very much!